# How to convert this php script to classic asp

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

I am trying to convert a PHP/JQuery sortable drag and drop script. I want to add JQuery sortable functionality to a site I have that is written in Classic ASP.

Here is a scaled down version of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {
          var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
        $("#info").load("process-sorttest.asp?"+order);
        alert('' + order);
      }
    });
});
</script>

<li id="listItem_1"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 1</strong></li>
<li id="listItem_2"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 2</strong></li>
```

The Jquery sortable side of the script works perfect. My problems accur trying to save the updated data back to the database.

Here is the PHP version of the script that I would like to convert to ASP:

```
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item) :
    $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
endforeach;

print_r ($sql);
```

This is the closest I can get in classic asp:

```
For Each Item In Request.QueryString
    Response.write "Processing: " & Request.QueryString("listItem[]") & "<br />"
Next
```

This gives me the ID's of the menu item I am modifiying however the reason I want to convert this script is because the PHP script reads and prints both the new order of the sort and the ID of the list item.
All that my asp prints are the ID of the list items "Processing 1, 2"

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Jason, your ability to answer your question (or get it answered) has to do with you taking the time to whittle it down. Whittle (or bracket) the question down, get rid of the JQuery part (which works fine) and get some tests running on the server side only (sending query strings yourself from the browser by using blah.asp?item=whatever)... obviously your For Each works but your Reuqest.Querystring is not picking out the right item. Start digging (otherwise I'll have to start up an IIS instance).

Answer (score 3):

The "For Each ... Next" construct in ASP works like this:

```
For Each <itemvar> In <collectionvar>
    ...
Next
```

Each iteration of the loop will put one item from collectionvar into the variable itemvar (both being placeholders for actual variables/values). Currently, your loop is accessing Request.QueryString("listItem[]") which is the same no matter what iteration of the loop you're on. Instead, you need to use the "Item" variable you defined in your For Each loop to process different items on each time through the loop.

Comment: Do you mean like this:
For Each Item In Request.QueryString("listItem[]")
Response.write "Processing: " & Item & "<br />"
Next

Comment: Thanks Dav, your help was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but linking sucks in comments:

Your PHP code looks like it suffers from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. You might want to read up on that to make sure you don't make the same mistake in ASP.

What it comes down to, is that you shouldn't assume that user input to be safe. You're taking variables straight out of the query string and assuming them to be numbers. In fact, they could be partial SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Request.QueryString(Item)` instead of `Request.QueryString("listItem[]")`

The loop `For Each Item In Request.QueryString` doesn't produce anything for `listItem[]` and sure as heck doesn't produce anything for `"listItem[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this http://www.me-u.com/php-asp/ its not perfect but could be helpful